# how to delay the rendering of render function until usereffect calls in react

Tags: reactjs, authentication, aws-amplify

i want to run the **useEffect** first before the **render** function which is placed inside the `<Route />` tag starts to  render. i expect to get currently available user details through the API and assigne them to render function.

but render function runs before the UseEffect retrieve data from the API. so help me to find the solution.

---

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";

const ProtectedRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => {

  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
        
    setIsAuthenticated(
      Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({
        // bypassCache: false,
      })
        .then((user) => console.log(user))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <Route 
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
     
        (isAuthenticated ) ? (              
           children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              // pathname: "/login",
              pathname: "/create-profile",
              state: { from: location },
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  useEffect(() => {
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({
      // bypassCache: false,
    })
      .then((user) => user && setIsAuthenticated(true))
      .catch((err) => err && setIsAuthenticated(false));
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap that authentication stuff into a hook of your own, and then simply not render anything until it's ready:

```
function useIsAuthenticated() {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({})
      .then(setIsAuthenticated)
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
      });
  }, []);
  return isAuthenticated;
}

const ProtectedRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  const isAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticated(); // Will be the user if authenticated, null if busy, or false if error.

  if (isAuthenticated === null) {
    return null; // Don't render anything if authentication state is unknown
  }
  return <>...</>;
};
```